# Adjusting String length

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV with fixed height and the text what i can echo here is of max 100 Characters.
But what I get is Dynamic text. This can also cantain 500 Characters.

And this text may also contain html tags.

Now I can simply take the first 100 Characters, as it can cut the tag.
Like

```
<string> Sample Text Here</st ...
```

And this will make the contents of the complete website BOLD.

Which will a better way to do this?

Comment: So you want the first 100 characters that are outside the html tags? i.e.: `<p>test</p>` is 4 character long?

Comment: Or is it that you want the first 100 chars (of text **and** tags), but stretch or shrink the range to include only matching/closed tag pairs? i.e do not truncate in the middle of a tag.

Comment: You've tagged both PHP and ColdFusion... which are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to strip the HTML tags and then trim to the first 100 characters:

```
#left(reReplace(variables.inputString,'<[^>]+>','','ALL'), 100)#
```

Answer (score 0):

May be like this.

```
<cfset strWithoutTag = rereplace(strWithTag,"<[\/]*\w+[^>]*>","","all")>
<cfdump var="#strWithoutTag#">
<cfset truncStr = left(strWithoutTag,100)>
<cfdump var="#truncStr#">
```